# Convert TabActivity to Fragments

Tags: android

I have a `TabActivity` implemented for my project which is running fine up to 2.3 versions, but crashes for versions greater than 3.How can I convert the code written for `TabHostActivity` to `Fragments`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add **android-support-v4.jar** file  for supporting Fragments in android 3.0 lower versions.Follow below link for downloading jar file.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidsupportv4jar.htm

Comment: I think u got it wrong..I want to convert my code which is written using TabActivity to Fragments.

Comment: If you want use Fragment concept in below Android3.0 versions you can't run.For that you need to add the above jar file to your project.You mentioned that 'I want convert tabactivity to Fragments' so I gave the above answer.

Comment: Ok..Is there any tutorial for converting tabhost to fragments in higher versions?

Comment: That will depend on your UI and Functional requirements

Answer (score 1):

[Learn how to implement fragments](https://web.archive.org/web/20130118120808/http://android10.org/index.php/articlesuserinterface/309-learn-how-to-implement-fragments-in-android) and also [to allow lower versions to use fragments](https://web.archive.org/web/20130117085453/http://android10.org/index.php/articlesuserinterface/311-android-compatibility-fragments-for-all)